# How do I implement filtering with Node.js and MySQL?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, backend

I'm currently learning how to implement filtering, sort, and pagination in a Node.js and MySQL backend.

The current solution I have is:

```
exports.getAll = (req, res) => {
    let params = {
        target_muscle: (req.query.target_muscle ? req.query.target_muscle : 'target_muscle')
    }
    Exercise.getAll(params, (error, result) => {
        if(error)
            res.status(500).send({
                message: error.message
            });
        else
            res.send(result);
    })
}
```

on the controller which calls this method from the model:

```
Exercise.getAll = (params, result) => {
    db.query("SELECT\
    exercise_id,\
    username AS author,\
    title, target_muscle,\
    sets, reps, duration,\
    likes,\
    video_id\
    FROM exercises\
    JOIN users ON exercises.author_id = users.user_id\
    WHERE target_muscle=?", [params.target_muscle], (error, res) => {
        if(error) {
            result(error, null);
            return;
        }
        result(null, res);
    })
}
```

It works fine when I actually have a query parameter passed on the GET request but gives me an empty result when I don't pass any parameter. I expected it to be unfiltered when I didn't pass anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to validate if you have a param value before adding that condition to the where portion of your SQL query. The way you're doing it, your code is querying like this.

```
WHERE target_muscle = 'target_muscle'
```